# How to play cmaf video format on android TV leanback media player?

Tags: android-mediaplayer, exoplayer, android-tv, leanback

I developed an Android TV application, using the leanback library.  The video screen, which extends the leanback VideoSupportFragment, uses MediaPlayer (not Exoplayer, unfortunately).  The problem is in the new format of the content which I should support, cmaf. It seems like by default MediaPlayer cannot process this media format and I'm not able to find any solution, except replacing the whole leanback VideoSupportFragment with my own custom one, with Exoplayer implementation. Is there any way to "teach" the MediaPlayer to work with cmaf format?